# Collection method find is synchronous

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Facing this error only when using find,findone is working fine.
Getting  "throw new Error('Collection method ' + i + ' is synchronous');"

index.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { database } = require("./server");

database();

let db = mongoose.connection;
let Products = db.collection("Products");

async function FindProd() {
  let findProd = await Products.find(
    { price: { $gte: 200 } },
    { projection: { price: 1, _id: 0 } }
  );
  console.log(findProd);
}
FindProd();
```

server.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let database = function () {
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb", (err, res) => {
    if (res) {
      console.log("connection successfull");
    } else {
      console.log("error:", err);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = { database };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `mongodb` method, but your assumption is that you're using a `mongoose` method.

With [`mongodb`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/), [`collection.find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/classes/Collection.html#find) is a synchronous method that will return a [`FindCursor`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/classes/FindCursor.html) that you can iterate over.

With [`mongoose`](https://mongoosejs.com/), [`Model.find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) will return a [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) that, for all intents and purposes, can be used as a Promise and thus be `await`'ed on.

You have two ways to solve your problem:

- convert your code to proper Mongoose by creating a schema and model for `Products`, or:
- use the `mongodb` driver as intended (don't use `mongoose` at all) and either iterate over the cursor *or* (if your result set isn't too large) use [`FindCursor.toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray):

  ```
  let findProd = await Products.find(…).toArray();
  ```

Comment: Tried this "let findProd = await Products.find(…).toArray();" , but same error.

Comment: @Sibi but are you still using `mongoose` to make the connection? If you want to use `toArray()`, you should really convert your code to `mongodb` instead.